# How to calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?

Tags: c#, date

How can one calculate the number of days between two dates in C#?

Comment: The addition and subtraction operators are overloaded for the `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` types as you would expect.  It's all pretty straightforward. -- What exact problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 2609, accepted):

Assuming `StartDate` and `EndDate` are of type `DateTime`:

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```

Comment: This answer is obviously correct, but you can also use `(a - b).Days` if you are interested in the total days as an `int` rather than a `double` with a decimal representation of the partial day difference.

Comment: this will return 1 less days, 08/31/2013-08/01/2013=31 but this is returning 30 only.

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi - you might want to check your maths. What is 31 - 1?

Comment: JasRaj was also right in a sense that inclusive both dates it returns a day less in difference. It all depends upon the perspective.

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua I came here looking for way to find difference between dates.  To add:  When talking about dates as whole days, the whole day would be considered for Aug 1.  Therefore, it would be subtracted from the Aug 31, and leave only 30 days.  It is incorrect to think otherwise.

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua It's not a matter or perspective but a matter of time, I mean, the time part of the date. 08/31/2013 - 08/01/2013 really means 08/31/2013 00:00:00 - 08/01/2013 00:00:00 which explains why it's 30 days, because the 08/31/2013 day is just starting. That also explains why, when querying on a DateTime property/field, the proper condition to get a range is "DateTimeProperty **>=** FromDate && DateTimeProperty **<** ToDate.AddDays(1)"

Comment: To get totaldays difference including enddate, (int) (this.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(1).Date - this.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date).TotalDays. In my case date variables are nullable.

Comment: "Inclusive both dates" is not a matter of perspective, unless you truly believe that the difference between today and tomorrow is two days...

Comment: public static int DaysBetween(DateTime now , DateTime then)
        {
            var _now = now.Date;
            var _then= then.Date;
            return (int)(_now - _then).TotalDays;
        }

Comment: Strange, if the year differs, when I run this code, it at max returns 365 days. Doesn't seem to work across years. Maybe it's just me? lol!??

Comment: If you need to count day boundaries like SQL Server [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql), this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: While I appreciate this solution I want to stress there are two ways to count days: 1. How many integers 24 hours has passed and 2.the more mundane way of counting how many midnights has passed.

Comment: Assuming both are of `DateTime`, for my solution which only requires no of days, I used:
`(EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).Days`

Comment: I know this post is a bit old... but regarding the date difference debate, here is the other perspective. If your start date at work is Monday and your end date is Tuesday then you worked for two days, not one. And to calcualte you will use `.Date`

Answer (score 387):

The top answer is correct, however if you would like only WHOLE days as an int and are happy to forgo the time component of the date then consider:

```
(EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).Days
```

Again assuming `StartDate` and `EndDate` are of type `DateTime`.

Comment: The best answer because _"numbers of days"_ normally means whole days. It's worth noting that [`Days`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't stop at 365 (as other properties like `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Second` which nax value is where the next higher property begins). Its the same as `TotalDays` but without fractions of a day and returning `int` instead of `double`.

Comment: Will this always work as expected? For example, if one of the days being compared is a "spring ahead" Daylight Saving Time day, could the subtraction produce a TimeSpan of 23 hours, and if so, would the value of .Days on that 23-hour time span be 0?  (I tried experimenting with this myself, but my results are inconclusive so far - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644252/why-doesnt-subtracting-two-local-datetime-values-appear-to-account-for-daylight)

Comment: Yup, this is what I needed - most valuable answer cmon now nobody wants to think about Minutes and Seconds in calculating days

Comment: if only 1,5 day has passed this .Days function will show only 1 Day? how i can alter it to show 2 days? i just have to always add + 1 day?

Comment: Upvoting this, because very often you would need "CALENDAR days between two dates", not just "number of 24-hour intervals". For example, you need to display an "X days ago" label in a timeline. In this case the difference between "Monday 11:59 pm" and "Tuesday 7:00 am" should be "1 day (ago)"... So the `.Date` part is really useful. Hope I'm making myself clear

Comment: I had a problem with my code where the difference in days between two days sometimes had some seconds difference and the rounding removed a day. This method solved the issue.

Answer (score 161):

Use TimeSpan object which is the result of date substraction:

```
DateTime d1;
DateTime d2;
return (d1 - d2).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 59):

I think this will do what you want:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

TimeSpan t = d1 - d2;
double NrOfDays = t.TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 37):

```
DateTime xmas = new DateTime(2009, 12, 25);
double daysUntilChristmas = xmas.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Anyway to get the days in between in DateTime format? Because I need each date to modify a certain field in tables :)
Edit: Got it and posted it as answer below. Thanks

Comment: DateTime xmas = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 12, 25); would make it work on a year by year basis, not just 2009 :)

Comment: Subtract() is the OperatorOverload for DateTimes so its the same "(xmas - DateTime.Today).TotalDays - just longer.

Answer (score 30):

```
// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.

TimeSpan ts = EndDate - StartDate;

// Difference in days.

int differenceInDays = ts.Days; // This is in int
double differenceInDays= ts.TotalDays; // This is in double

// Difference in Hours.
int differenceInHours = ts.Hours; // This is in int
double differenceInHours= ts.TotalHours; // This is in double

// Difference in Minutes.
int differenceInMinutes = ts.Minutes; // This is in int
double differenceInMinutes= ts.TotalMinutes; // This is in double
```

You can also get the difference in seconds, milliseconds and ticks.

Answer (score 23):

In case someone wants numer of whole days as a double (`a`, `b` of type `DateTime`):

```
 (a.Date - b.Date).TotalDays
```

Comment: This will always be a whole number though (i.e., n.00000) because the Date portion is always midnight.

Answer (score 23):

There often is a debate on time (hours) when it comes to counting days between two dates. The responses to the question and their comments show no exception.

Considering `StartDate` and `EndDate` are of type `DateTime`: if performance is not a concern, I would strongly recommend documenting your calculation through intermediate conversions. For example, `(EndDate - StartDate).Days` is unintuitive because rounding will depend on the hour component of `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

- If you want the duration in days to include fractions of days, then as already suggested
  use `(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays`.
- If you want the duration to reflect
  the distance between two days, then use `(EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).Days`
- If you want the duration to reflect the
  duration between the morning of the start date, and the evening of
  the end date (what you typically see in project management software), then use
  `(EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).Days + 1`

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
EndDate.Date.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Date).Days
```

Comment: This actually helped me the best as my date difference was half a day but still when America is 1 day behind Australia I need to see there's actually one day difference. The other answers mentioned in this thread was showing either zero or some double number below 1 which I don't need.

Comment: This is the best answer when the purpose is to check if the date has already passed to the next day, no matter if in terms of time is not a full 24h day.

Comment: The best answer to exact difference without considering timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

Using a timespan would solve the problems as it has many attributes:

```
DateTime strt_date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime("10/1/2017 23:59:59");
//DateTime add_days = end_date.AddDays(1);
TimeSpan nod = (end_date - strt_date);
Console.WriteLine(strt_date + "" + end_date + "" + "" + nod.TotalHours + "");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

For `a` and `b` as two `DateTime` types:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
DateTime c = DateTime.Now;
c = d.AddDays(145);
string cc;
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(c);
var t = (c - d).Days;
Console.WriteLine(t);
cc = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

For beginners like me that will stumble upon this tiny problem, in a simple line, with sample conversion to **int**:

```
int totalDays = Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.UtcNow.Date - myDateTime.Date).TotalDays);
```

This calculates the total days from today (DateTime.UtcNow.Date) to a desired date (myDateTime.Date).

If myDateTime is yesterday, or older date than today, this will give a positive (+) integer result.

On the other side, if the myDateTime is tomorrow or on the future date, this will give a negative (-) integer result due to rules of addition.

Happy coding! ^_^

Comment: Couldn't you just use "Days" instead of casting TotalDays? That conversion doesn't even round, it just truncates. if TotalDays is 1.99, your solution will give 1 (which may be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

First declare a class that will return later:

```
public void date()
{
    Datetime startdate;
    Datetime enddate;
    Timespan remaindate;

    startdate = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text).Date;
    enddate = DateTime.Parse(txtenddate.Text).Date;

    remaindate = enddate - startdate;

    if (remaindate != null)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "you have left with " + remaindate.TotalDays + "days.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "correct your code again.";
    }
}

protected void btncal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date();
}
```

Use a button control to call the above class. Here is an example:

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference between the two dates and then get the days from:

```
int total_days = (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: TotalDays returns a double: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx
So you need a conversion to int

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
 int DateDifInSecond = EndDate.Subtract(StartDate).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score -4):

try this truly worked Get actual days diff. date format is "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
  string[] d1 = txtFromDate.Values.Split('/');
  string[] d2 = txtToDate.Values.Split('/');

  DateTime FrmDt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(d1[2]), Convert.ToInt32(d1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(d1[0]));
  DateTime ToDt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(d2[2]), Convert.ToInt32(d2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(d2[0]));

  TimeSpan TDiff = ToDt.Subtract(FrmDt);
  String DaysDiff = TDiff.TotalDays.ToString();
```

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` exists. You can specify the format without resorting to parsing it manually. This answer doesn't add anything that the existing answers don't already provide.

Answer (score -27):

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    // int a;
    TextBox2.Text = d.ToShortDateString();
    string s = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text).ToShortDateString();
    string s1 =  Convert.ToDateTime(Label7.Text).ToShortDateString();
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s).Date;
    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(s1).Date;
    if (dt <= dt1)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert(' Not a valid Date to extend warranty')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        string diff = dt.Subtract(dt1).ToString();
        Response.Write(diff);
        Label18.Text = diff;
        Session["diff"] = Label18.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong in so many ways! 1) Lots of Winforms code not related to the question. 2) Wired way of showing message boxes using (I guess an WebBrowser control). 3) using a WebBrowser control to show a text that is shown in label already. 4) Using the OperatorOverload Subtract() (default for "-" operations) which is used for anyway if you do a "MyDateA - MyDateB". 5) No explanation tho this pile of code.