# Adapting SQL to work over multiple weeks

Tags: sql-server

I have a report that determines employees that have entered less than 40 hours on their timesheets for a specific week:

```
With Under40s as (
Select Distinct Entry.UUID, Entry.FirstName, Entry.LastName, Team.PersonUnit, Team.TeamName
From Entry as Entry
Inner Join TeamOrganization as Team on Team.PersonUUID = Entry.UUID and @EnteredDate     between Team.PeriodBeginDate and Team.PeriodEndDate
Where 
(
    Select sum(Entry2.Hours) From Entry as Entry2
    Where Entry2.UUID = Entry.UUID and Entry2.Date Between @StartDate and @EndDate
) < 40
Or not exists 
(
    Select 1 From Entry as Entry2
    Where Entry2.UUID = Entry.UUID and Entry2.Date Between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
)
Select distinct Under40s.UUID, Under40s.FirstName, Under40s.LastName, Under40s.PersonUnit, Under40s.TeamName, Case
    When Sum(Entry.Hours) is null then 0
    Else Sum(Entry.Hours)
    End as TotalHours 
From Under40s
Left Join Entry as Entry on Entry.UUID = Under40s.UUID and Entry.Date Between @StartDate and @EndDate
Where Under40s.PersonUnit in (@PersonUnit) and Under40s.TeamName in (@Teams)
Group By Under40s.UUID, Under40s.FirstName, Under40s.LastName, Under40s.PersonUnit, Under40s.TeamName
Order By Under40s.LastName, Under40s.FirstName
```

The client now wants to be able to enter a date range of more than a week.  I'm thinking they want to see for each week within that date range, who's reporting less than 40 hours.  I am not sure how, or if, I can modify the SQL to deliver such a report.  Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using reporting services to display the output of this cte?

Comment: @SelectDistinct: Yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every working day is 8 hours, one option would be to get the the day differences between start date and end date and then multiplying that by 8 and using the product as the criteria. For example: startdate: 20/11/2013 and enddate: 31/12/2013 is 41 days including weekends (so you also you have to filter weekends or non-working days), but just as example 41*8 =  328. So instead of less than 40 it will be less than 328. Here's a link to a working solution of excluding weekends and other specified dates: [Number of days in date range, excluding weekends and other dates, in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537813/number-of-days-in-date-range-excluding-weekends-and-other-dates-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm thinking that what they really want is this: for the period 10/28/2013 to 11/17/2013, employee 1 reported 20 hours on week 1, employee 2 reported 35 hours on week 2, and employee 3 reported 15 hours on week 1 and 29 hours on week 2.  I'm just not sure how to deliver this.  I'm not sure it's even possible really.

Comment: Ah I see if that's what they want then I think he can get the weeks, then each week the start and end date and so on.

Comment: How would you do that with straight SQL?