# How to find the number of days between two dates / DateTimePickers

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

In my code below, how do I set up arrivaldate and depaturedate so I can get an amount due? I need to set them up as days stayed at the hotel so I can come up with a total. If this makes any sense? I am using datetimepickers in Visual Basic.

```
Public Class RentalForm
    'declare constants
    Const tax_rate_decimal As Decimal = 12.25D
    Const king_price_decimal As Decimal = 110.9D
    Const queen_price_decimal As Decimal = 105.9D
    Const double_price_decimal As Decimal = 95.9D

    'declare variables
    Private roomchargesumdecimal, taxamountsumdecimal, amountduesumdecimal As Decimal

    Private Sub exitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxnameofguest.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub calculateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click
        'dimension local variables
        Dim numberofguestsinteger As Integer
        Dim roomchargedecimal, taxamountdecimal, amountduedecimal, taxratedecimal As Integer
        Dim arrivaldate, departuredate As Date

        Try
            'dates
            arrivaldate = Now

            'convert quantity to numeric
            numberofguestsinteger = Integer.Parse(TextBoxNumberofguests.Text)

            'calculate values for single person
            roomchargedecimal = numberofguestsinteger * (arrivaldate + departuredate)
            taxratedecimal = roomchargedecimal * tax_rate_decimal   

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DateTimePickerarrivaldate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePickerarrivaldate.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label16averagelengthofstay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label16averagelengthofstay.Click


    End Sub

    Private Sub RentalForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Answer (score 18):

`DateTime` math can be confusing at first.  But it doesn't really matter if they are `DateTimePicker` controls or variables because `myDateTimePicker.Value` **is** a `DateTime` Type.  So, you can mix and match variables and controls such as Arrival as Now and Departure from a picker, and just use subtraction:

```
Dim arrivaldate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim departuredate As DateTime = Me.DeparturePicker.Value

Dim DaysStayed as Int32 = departuredate.Subtract(arrivaldate).Days
```

The thing to remember is that the result is a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) object. If you look at the structure, you'll see it provides the time elapsed in units from `Days` to `Ticks`.

The code above plucks the `Days` value from the `TimeSpan` without creating a temp `TimeSpan` var.  Another way:

```
Dim tsHotelStay = detarturedate.Value - arrivalDate
wholeDays = tsHotelStay.Days              ' e.g 7
totalDays = tsHotelStay.TotalDays         . e.g. 7.53
totalHrs = tsHotelStay.TotalHours         . eg 180.397
```

This time, the code *does* create a `TimeSpan` variable (`tsHotelDay`).  Note that all the properties are available in whole and fractional forms (except Ticks).

Finally, the 2 subtraction methods shown (`DateTime.Subtract(dt)` and `myTs = dtA - dtB`) are functionally identical: both return a TimeSpan object.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTimePicker objects have a [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx), which will give you a DateTime for each. You can get the difference two DateTime objects by subtracting one from the other.

P.S. Don't eat all exceptions like that. It's uncool.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use

```
`DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

to calculate number of date intervals (days) betveen two dates.