# How can I compute the total number of days worked using Date time picker

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datepicker

I have a table name `timelogTB` and it has **5** column named; `LogID(PK)`, `EmpNo(FK)`, `Time_In`, `Time_Out` and `Date` running in `form1`.

Then in `form2` I have a `combobox` where the Employee # of an employee can be selected and when I will select an Employee # the total number of days worked of that employee will display in a `textbox` using 2 date time picker,

the `dtpicker1` is labeled `dtpFrom` and `dtpicker2` is labeled `dtpTo`.

The column `Date` in `timelogTB` is only recording the date when the employee is time in using also a date time picker.

I am looking forward for a favorable answer guys, as much as possible I want you to explain it more simpler and precise because I am new in `vb2010`

thanks in advance!

Comment: explain ko sa tagalog?

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen: Mas ok po para mas madali maintindihan.

Comment: Need mo ng sql code or script pra mkuha mo ung difference ng 2 dates. ung script na un ung ilalagay mo dun sa button. Pra pag select ka ng date sa datetimepicker tapos nagclick ka dun sa button matic na lalabas sa textbox ung Total number of hours or difference ng 2 dates.

Comment: Are you wanting to know what the difference in days is between `dtpFrom` and `dtpTo`? If it is then have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017466/how-to-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-datetimepickers). @Plutonix answer should give you what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

oh kaya try mo to

`txthours.text=datediff(DateInterval.hours,Time_In,Time_Out).ToString()`

Assuming ung name ng textbox mo ay `txthours.text.` lagay mo nalang sa button

Comment: boss meron na po ako ganitong code. bali yung program ko kasi na ginagawa is payroll system so sa form 1 kasi doon sila nag la login ma rerecord dun yung date at time sa pag login nila. sa form 2 meron akong combo box na dun naka lagay yung mga employee #, pag click mo ng employee # lalabas yung basic info ng employee pati na din yung total days work nya within range. bali diba dito sa atin pag sahod meron mang 1-15 at 16-30 bali yun sana ang gusto kung i compute gamit yung dalawang date time picker sa form 2.

Comment: bali extracted yung records nila sa form 1 kung ilang araw sila pumasok lets say from january 1-15 ilang araw sya pumasok.

Comment: bale prang gusto mo mangyare pagka click mo ng employeeid sa combobox mavview na dn ung no. of working days sa form 2 basic info?

Comment: oo boss ganun na nga.

Comment: sa pag compute ko ng age at years in the company. iba naman yun sya sa registration yun ng employee bro.