# How to subtract two calendar dates from each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

How can I subtract two calendar dates from each other.

For instance: 
05-05-2014 minus 03-02-2013 and then it'll calculate the difference between the dates in years, months, hours and minutes.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days

Comment: Use the "new DateTime()" then use the ".Subtract" routine. This is pretty basic and there are other stack questions about this. You might look around first before asking : )

Comment: @drew_w He may actually just take a language tutorial - this is likely one of the basic examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var end=DateTime.Parse("05-05-2014");
var start=DateTime.Parse("03-02-2013");
TimeSpan difference=(end-start);
```

Or as in the comment. You can use `DateTime.Subtract()` like this:

```
TimeSpan difference=end.Subtract(start);
```

**Edit**

If you look at the DateTime class in the a reflector. You will find this:

```
public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return new TimeSpan(d1.InternalTicks - d2.InternalTicks);
}
public TimeSpan Subtract(DateTime value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(this.InternalTicks - value.InternalTicks);
}
```

Both the `operator` and the `Subtract` method uses the same code. So yes it is the same thing. It is just what you personally prefer.

Comment: Personally I prefer DateTime.Subtract() but I believe yours does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Date can be substracted from one another, and will return a TimeSpan. You can access the value of the TimeSpan to find out its value in years, days, etc...

```
var ts = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
// ts.Days is the number of days between now and the first of january 2014
```

Comment: +1. It is really that simple and something obvious when reading the documentation for the basic types.

Comment: Sure you can post the explanation... But what about a working piece of code?