# How to find number of days from two string type dates?

Tags: c#

I have two text box dates (8/11/2014) and (9/11/2014). I want to find the number of days between these two dates. I am getting some string error message. Please help me..

Comment: Convert them to proper DateTime values, then subtract one from the other.

Comment: Can you post the code along with the error message? My psychic ability is playing up today.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, If you dont mind please let me know how to convert these string dates into datetime value?

Comment: @DwaneMarsh: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx  Seriously, not to sound snarky here, but at least *try* Google.

Comment: eh, I could understand someone new to programming not knowing how to research libraries.  You gotta learn how to learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse both dates and then substract them and count total days like this:

```
DateTime date1 =   DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date2 =   DateTime.ParseExact(dateString2, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var days = (int)(date2-date1).TotalDays;
```

Comment: My date1 is (txtdate) and date2 is (txtdate1). How it convert to DateTime

Comment: Just change dateString1 to txtdate and dateString2 to txtdate1

Comment: Also notice that i assumed that 11 is a month. If it is a day you should change pattern to: "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: @Paweł Reszka, It works but it shows date with time like 12:00:00 Am, so I didint get the expected output. how to change this date format??

Comment: 12:00:00 am is the beggining of the day. It's like you have 0 hours, minutes and seconds in you DateTime. In C# there is not type like Date, where you don't have hours, minutes etc

Comment: Is it causing any problems? Calculated days should be correct.

Comment: Yes it shows output as 1.0

Comment: Because its returning double. Check in a second my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

I feel taking risk to answer this but..

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to parse your strings and subtract each other and use [`TimeSpan.TotalDays` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.totaldays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use [`TimeSpan.Days` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well if you are interested in the total days as an `int` rather than a `double`.

```
string txtdate = "8/11/2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdate, "d/MM/yyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{

}
string txtdate1 = "9/11/2014";
DateTime dt1;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdate1, "d/MM/yyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt1))
{

}

var totaldays = (dt1 - dt).Days; // 1
```

You [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780731/how-to-find-number-of-days-from-two-string-type-dates/26780844?noredirect=1#comment42139772_26780844);

> I need output as 8/11/2014-9/11/2014=1. But I applied your code it
>   shows output like 1.0?

I told you `TotalDays` property returns `double` and `Days` property returns `int`. But besides that, you seems like a result as `9/11/2014 - 8/11/2014 = 1` instead of just `1`. In such a case, you can use `string.Format` like;

```
var result = string.Format("{0} - {1} = {2}",
                           dt1.ToString("d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                           dt.ToString("d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                           totaldays);
```

`result` will be `9/11/2014 - 8/11/2014 = 1`

Comment: Sorry 8 and 9 are days it is in the format of "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: @DwaneMarsh What do you mean they are _dates_? You mean days? And what do you expect as a result of total days?

Comment: Pardon it is days. Typing mistake

Comment: @DwaneMarsh You can use `d/MM/yyyy` format in such a case. Updated my answer. But really, what do you want as an output of total days?

Comment: I need output as 8/11/2014-9/11/2014=1. But I applied your code it shows output like 1.0?

Comment: @DwaneMarsh Updated my question. Use `Days` if you want to return `int` as a result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Soner Gönül for spend your valuable time with my foolish question. I got answer. Even though I understood something ..