# Difference between two dates and .NET function DaysInMonth

Tags: c#, datetime

Following code return 30 days instead of 31 days.

```
DateTime dtFromDate   = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-01");
DateTime dtToDateDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-31");     
NoOfDays  =  (int) (dtToDateDate- dtFromDate).TotalDays;
```

and the following code return 31 days.

```
NoOfDays = (int)DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015,1);
```

How to calculate exact no of days between two dates?

Comment: How could that return 31 days? Does 31 -1 equals 31 ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days), kindly make sure to read the comments on the mentioned duplicate.

Comment: FYI, this is not a "built in C# function". It's a .NET Framework method on the .NET Framework `System.DateTime` type.

Comment: Rohit   why 31-1, what if we want to calculate no of days in a month we subtract first date to last date? and how the DaysInMonth Calculate no of days

Comment: @AbrarAhmad, its simple logic, if you have to count number of days from 1st to 31st, then you complete your one day at 2nd date, two day at 3rd date and so 30th on 31st date.

Comment: If you want to count the number of whole numbers between 1 and 10 you don't subtract 10 from 1 (10 - 1 = 9).

Answer (score 1):

in the first one you omitted all days at and before "2015-01-01" from the date "2015-01-31". which is logically 30 (2015/1/31 included)

in the second you are just asking number of days in January which is 31

Nothing is not normal here

Answer (score 1):

That's because the day starts from 00:00:00 hour (midnight),  so for 31/1 so it will not be included,  but if you added the hours you will get the valid number of days. Or you can change the enddate to be "1/2/2015 00:00:00" and you will get the valid numbers too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I want to write more explanation if you guys let me!

Let's look at your examples line by line;

```
DateTime dtFromDate   = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-01");
DateTime dtToDateDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-31");
```

With this conversation, your `dtFromDate` will be `01/01/2015 00:00:00` and `dtToDateDate` will be `31/01/2015 00:00:00` since you didn't write any time part, it will be assigned to midnight by default.

With `dtToDateDate- dtFromDate` line, you will get a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) which is *exactly* 30 day long as `{30.00:00:00}`. Why? *Well*, simple;

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|      FirstDate      |      LastDate       | Day Difference |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 0              |
| 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 02/01/2015 00:00:00 | 1              |
| 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 03/01/2015 00:00:00 | 2              |
| ...                 | ...                 | ...            |
| ...                 | ...                 | ...            |
| 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 31/01/2015 00:00:00 | 30             |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

But how about `DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 1)`?

[`DaysInMonth` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of days in the specified month and year. Since [October](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October) has `31` days in [Gregorian Calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), it returns `31`.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October);

> October is the tenth month of the year in the Julian and Gregorian
>   Calendars and one of seven months **with a length of 31 days**.

But this method doesn't use any `DateTime` difference to calculate them. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,63171f0b203c9692):

```
public static int DaysInMonth(int year, int month)
{
    // IsLeapYear checks the year argument
    int[] days = IsLeapYear(year)? DaysToMonth366: DaysToMonth365;
    return days[month] - days[month - 1];
}
```

Since `2015` is not a [leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), `days` array will be equal to [`DaysToMonth365`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,81b15ba4edf14ced) which is defined as;

```
private static readonly int[] DaysToMonth365 =
{
   0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365
};
```

And we provided `month` parameter as `1`, this method returns

```
days[1] - days[0]
```

which is equal to

```
31 - 0
```

which is equal to `31`.

Comment: After I complete this answer, I feel like this is the most unnecessary explanation I have ever written.