# Subtracting dates in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on subtracting dates in a web form in visual studio 2012 using a begin and end date - I want to find the day difference.

I have two separate web forms that I have connected.

```
DateTime ArrivalDateCalc = Convert.ToDateTime(.Text)
```

is what I have tried to use, but it does not work.

Any clues or guidance?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "does not work"?  Do you get an exception?  Is the value wrong?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? .Text in Convert.ToDateTime(.Text) seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days

Answer (score 2):

You can use .Subtract to subtract dates in C#:

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);
```

The result is TimeSpan, which you can get Day, Year etc from it..

Answer (score 2):

You can Subtract two dates to find out the days difference.

```
string sdate = "2018-08-25";
string edate = "2018-08-23";

double days = (Convert.ToDateTime(sdate) - Convert.ToDateTime(edate)).TotalDays;
Response.Write("Difference = " + days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is very unclear, but assuming you are using some format;

```
string startDateInText = "01/01/2014";
string endDateInText = "31/12/2014";
System.DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDateInText, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
System.DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDateInText , "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

System.TimeSpan diff = endDate.Subtract(startDate);
//diff.Days will provide difference in Days`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `"-"` operator to get the difference.

e.g.

```
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date2 - date3;
```

You can use the `Day` property of timespan object to get the difference

Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx) reference link