# Display the remaining days

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net system that have a PODate field with Datetime value in the database. How do I minus the days left until the delivery arrive. I want to show it in a column in a list view

Example: The date of delivery is on Oct 21. It must show 14 days to go before the delivery arrives.

Can it be done in a select query or it must be done in my visual studio.

Comment: which DB are you using? you can use date difference functions in SQL.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server` then you can use this query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,Column1,Column2) AS DiffDate from TableName
```

Or if you want to do this in `c#` then you can use `TimeSpan` object

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime date2;
return (date1 - date2).TotalDays;
```

If your Subquery is returning only one value then you can try

```
SELECT ABS((SELECT DATEDIFF(day,Column1,Column2) AS DiffDate from TableName))
```

Comment: I'll go with query, but it is showing a negative value. Can it be turn into a Positive

Comment: Use the absolute value function ABS. The syntax is ABS ( numeric_expression )

Comment: I have tried, I think I'm doing it wrong can you edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do with **c#**

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime date2;
return (date1 - date2).Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

may this help you to find differences.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), deliveryDate) AS DayDiff
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), deliveryDate) AS MinuteDiff
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), deliveryDate) AS SecondDiff
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, GETDATE(), deliveryDate) AS WeekDiff
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), deliveryDate) AS HourDiff
```

Comment: I have tried it and it works, but it is showing a negative days. Can it be positive day

Comment: try it out SELECT FORMAT(DATEDIFF( day, GETDATE(), deliveryDate),'+#;-#;0')

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in both,

> I would prefer it to be done in Visual Studio, as this is clearly presentation
>   logic.

**C#**

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2002,7,15);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
// Difference in days.
int differenceInDays = ts.Days;

Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: {0} ", differenceInDays);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287590%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**VB**

```
Dim firstDate, msg As String 
Dim secondDate As Date
firstDate = InputBox("Enter a date")
Try
    secondDate = CDate(firstDate)
    msg = "Days from today: " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now, secondDate)
    MsgBox(msg)
Catch
    MsgBox("Not a valid date value.")
End Try
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This work, how can I arrange it by nearest date for arrival

Comment: You are try to get the difference between to dates right. what is to be arranged here ? Could you please be more clear ..