# check the license generated dates belongs to this year

Tags: c#, .net

I have got two dates on which legacy license has been generated by a customer

These are the date formats `02-03-2015, 09-08-2015` , so i need to give him a error saying that u have exceeded the license generation count.

because, only two times a customer can generate the license in a year, I am struggling how to compare the two given dates with in the year and whether this belongs to this year (or) not ..

I am using C# for this validation , would any one please suggest nay idea  on how to do this ...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You means that user will input 2 datetimes (date1 and date2), and you need to check if the period between those datetimes is in current year or not?

Comment: I do not understand. Do you mean the time windows between the two given dates needs to be < 365 days or do you need to check if both dates are in the year same year for example 2015?

Comment: @tdat00 sorry for late reply .. I mean any customer cannot generate more than two licenses per year this is restriction that i need to put .... would you please help..

Comment: @STORM  sorry for late reply .. I mean any customer cannot generate more than two licenses per year this is restriction that i need to put .... would you please help.

Comment: Do you mean within the year 2015 for example only two times? Or between the two dates or we need a clearer description of what you want to do.

Comment: When i correctly understand your requirement that you only have to check if these two years belong to the same year, than please take the second part of my answer!

Comment: with in  the year a customer can able to generate only two license and if he try to generate one more i need to warn saying that u have exceeded the limit for current year .. would you please help on this ...

Comment: i have got db structure like this createdDate, licKey , userName... so i need check that createdDate with the  user ..

Comment: I have edited my answer completely! Please have a look at it. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a SELECT on your DB table with the licenses where you check for the year of the createdAt Date and the user

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM licTable WHERE year(createdate_column) = 2015 AND user = 123
```

If the result (count of the returned records) is >= 2 then you throw an error!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading this link: 
[Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```

If you have result > 365 then you can assume that user had exceeded licence generation count

Here's how I'd do it:

```
    private bool AllowToRenew(List<DateTime> renewalDateList)
    {
        var date = renewalDateList.OrderBy(x => x).First().AddYears(-1);
        return renewalDateList.Count(x => x > date) > 1;

    }
```

Comment: @Edgaras sorry for late reply .. I mean any customer cannot generate more than two licenses per year this is restriction that i need to put .... would you please help.

Comment: Does that makes any sense to you? renewalDateList is your list of dates "02-03-2015, 09-08-2015"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RangeValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, set the type as Date and set the Min and Max from code behind