# Calculating Days in C# Objects That Are Instantiated Using a LINQ Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, date, datetime

I have a column of Datetime values in a table. I am using a LINQ query in a Controller to create model objects, where I am trying to perform a calculation to return the amount of days since the date value until now. The result updates another string variable depending on the result's value.

This is the LINQ query

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = from a in db.area
                     join c in db.sample
                     on a.location_id equals c.location_id into samples
                     let sample = samples.OrderByDescending(c => c.date_sampled).FirstOrDefault()
                     select new StatusModel
                     {
                         location_name = a.location_name,
                         latitude = a.latitude,
                         longitude = a.longitude,
                         status = sample.sample_status,
                         sampDate = sample.sample_date ?? DateTime.Now
                     };
        return View(result);
    }
```

And this is the method and constructor from my StatusModel to perform the calculation.

```
   public int difference;

    public StatusModel()
    {
        setStatus();
    }


    public void setStatus()
    {
        DateTime oldDate = sampDate;
        DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
        difference = ts.Days;
    }
```

The setStatus method works fine when I manually type in a date, i.e. if I set

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2016,2,9);
```

It returns as expected. However using the sampDate variable, it returns '736047' as the number of days for everything! The date in my database is set like '2016-01-04', when I run my project all dates in the Views are converted to MM-DD-YYYY, perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the code you've presented, so I would suspect that the dates in your database are somehow not getting converted properly to .NET `DateTime` values or the dates in your database are not being stored properly in the first place.

Comment: @emerfan - can you paste full StatusModel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation:

```
   var x = new StatusModel {
           location_name = a.location_name,
           latitude = a.latitude,
           longitude = a.longitude,
           status = sample.sample_status,
           sampDate = sample.sample_date ?? DateTime.Now
    }
```

means exacly this:

```
var x = new StatusModel();

x.location_name = a.location_name;
x.latitude = a.latitude;
x.longitude = a.longitude;
x.status = sample.sample_status;
x.sampDate = = sample.sample_date ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Firstly, this code will run constructor for `StatusModel`, then it will insert values for properties. What is important in your case:

```
public StatusModel()
{
    setStatus();
}
```

You are running method `setStatus()` in your constructor, which is setting value for `difference`.

But this method is using `sampDate` which is not "initialized" yet - so `sampDate` will have a default value for `DateTime`, which is `0001-01-01`. So now you have a reason, why `difference` returns 736047 days, because you are 
subtracting 2016-0001 (approximately).

Now it's time to resolve main issue - how to return difference of this two dates. It will be quite easy.

```
public int difference {
   get { return (sampDate - DateTime.Now).Days; }
}

public StatusModel()
{

}
```

Now you have a logic for `difference` in getter of this field, which is more "natural" in this case in my opinion. It will returns correct value for `difference` each time you will "ask" for value of this property, also during passing your model to view (using `return View(model);`)

Comment: Brilliant, really informative answer and thank you so much for the explanation - it makes perfect sense and was driving me nuts. I need to set a currentStatus based on the int difference, so I had placed the method in the constructor. Now I have a getter for currentStatus instead public string getStatus
        {get {if (difference >= 14){ return "Closed";}else{return status;}}

Answer (score 0):

The object initializer gets called after the constructor; your code:

```
new StatusModel
                     {
                         location_name = a.location_name,
                         latitude = a.latitude,
                         longitude = a.longitude,
                         status = sample.sample_status,
                         sampDate = sample.sample_date ?? DateTime.Now
                     };
```

Will set the **sampDate** after the **setStatus** is executed, therefore the sampDate of the function will always be **default(DateTime)** and give you the same result (unless you're running it around midnight).

Comment: Apparently my answer was not pretty enough.