# calculate number of days between 2 dates in php

Tags: php, date

I need to calculate difference between 2 dates here is my dates

```
$start = strtotime('17/05/2016');
$end = strtotime('12/05/2016');
```

I have tried

```
  echo $days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

But it shows output as 17140

Hep to find the number of days between 2 given dates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days?rq=1

Comment: `12/05/2016` is being read as december 5 2016. `17/05/2016` is read as invalid so it is empty. So your equation is `strtotime('12/05/2016') / 86400`.

Comment: Date format is not valid....

Comment: how to convert to valid format then calculate diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify what is the date format, so:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',"12/05/2016");
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',"17/05/2016");
echo $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a"); //output: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format:
with **d/m/Y** at **m/d/Y**

You can also use a format like this:

```
$s = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '17/05/2016');
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '05/12/2016');
```

And get the difference of days:

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '17/05/2016');
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/05/2016');
$interval = $end->diff($start);
$days = $interval->format('%a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong format for dates, the original is: "Y-m-d" not "d/m/Y", you can use something like this if you could change the date format:

```
 $now = strtotime("2016-05-17"); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime("2016-05-12");
 $datediff = $now - $your_date;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```