# find the number of days between dates C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a string that coming in date format date=08/21/2016 what I want to do is find the numbers of days From today's date in C# I have converted the string like this.

```
 DateTime Date = Convert.ToDayTime("08/21/2016"); 
 DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Today.Day;    
 DateTime SubDate = Date.Subtract(TodayDate);
```

On the third line, I'm getting error cannot convert 
     System.TimeSpan to System.DateTime

Is there an another way to do this what I want to do I just calculate numbers of days from a future date that is coming as a string

```
 Example 
 TodayDate=08/01/2016
 FutureDate=08/20/2016

 Answer 19 days
```

I'm new to C# if it's not to much trouble could somebody share code solution how to achieve this?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240244/329367

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no method called `Convert.ToDayTime` in the `Convert` class it should be `Convert.ToDateTime()`.

The DateTime allows you to subtract its object from another object of the same type. then You can make use of the  `.TotalDays` function to get the number of days. between those dates.

Use something like this:

```
DateTime futurDate = Convert.ToDateTime("08/21/2016");
DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Now;
var numberOfDays = (futurDate - TodayDate).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime FutureDate = DateTime.ParseExact("08/21/2016", "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Now;

int days = (FutureDate - TodayDate).Days;
```