# Calculating rent in hotel from checkin and checkout date asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Rent calculating for each day from check-in time and checkout time. If check-in at 31-08-2016 and checkout at 01-09-2016 then it was calculating rent to 30 days. But it has to calculate for only 1 day.

```
char sp = '/';
string[] date = checkin.Split(sp);
string[] date2 = checkout.Split(sp);
int c1 = Convert.ToInt32(date[0]);
int c0 = Convert.ToInt32(date2[0]);
totday = c0 - c1;
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Here is a clue - don't store dates in strings use the correct datatype. Start googling c# datatypes

Comment: Please state you question more clearly and think about values of intermediate variables in your code. [DateTime stuct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) might be helpful for you - [here you have some more details how to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days).

Comment: Please state your problem more clearly.

Comment: See this _[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Wy7RI)_ if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Judging you code, I'd say it calculates for minus 30 days even

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I'm not quite sure what is being asked here, but I'd recommend using the correct types. Here is a code snippet you may be asking for?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        DateTime checkIn = new DateTime(2016, 8, 31);
        DateTime checkOut = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1);

        TimeSpan difference = checkOut - checkIn;

        Console.WriteLine(difference);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. Do the arithmetic with `DateTime` objects. @satish, read up on properties and methods - these make arithmetic *easy* IF YOU KNOW THE SECRET:  **Key to understanding DateTime:** Every DateTime always has the "fully qualified value"  consisting of year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds. If you don't want the *time*, for example, to factor into any calculations make sure time is set to zero. The `Date` property returns the datetime object with hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds all zeroed.