# Calculate the elapsed time from a date vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datetime, elapsedtime

I need to get the elapsed time from a date, for example:

I have this line

```
 Mon, 12 Sep 2016 10:20:00 +0100
```

If the datetime now is:

```
12/09/2016 10:40:02
```

And I need to get this as final result:

```
20 mins ago
```

Another example for the same question to explain it better:
If I have this date:

```
Sun, 11 Sep 2016 09:18:13 +0100
```

The final result should be :

```
1 day ago
```

But if time does not become 24 hours, then it puts the hours since that date, for example:

```
Sun, 11 Sep 2016 11:18:13 +0100
```

The result will be:

```
23 hours ago
```

And the same if the elapsed date is a month or years, 
from example:
For this date:

```
Sun, 11 Ago 2016 11:18:13 +0100
```

Result:

```
1 month ago
```

And,

```
Sun, 11 Ago 2015 11:18:13 +0100
```

Result:

```
1 year ago
```

How can I get this? thanks for help

Comment: I have to add that can I have this date: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 12:29:09 +0100 with (+0100) or this other date for example: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 15:40:23 +0200 with this (+0200)

Comment: why don't you use `TimeSapn`?

Comment: [Pretty Date](https://www.dotnetperls.com/pretty-date) will help :)

Answer (score 6):

You can directly subtract your start DateTime from end DateTime if both are of same type.

```
var difference = endDateTime - startDateTime;
```

Once you get your difference then its just matter of formatting your output string.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607352/6170142)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer):

```
// For DateTime
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-30).Humanize() // returns "yesterday"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2).Humanize()  // returns "2 hours ago"

// For TimeSpan
TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Humanize(precision:2) // "1 day"
TimeSpan.FromDays(16).Humanize(2) // "2 weeks, 2 days"
```

More samples you can find on [github](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-timespan)

Comment: Nice extension             .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) function.