# Why doesn't subtracting two local DateTime values appear to account for Daylight Saving Time?

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

I'm playing with some C# code to try to gain an understanding of how subtracting DateTime objects in C# works with respect to Daylight Saving Time.

Per Google and other sources, the Daylight Saving Time "spring ahead" event in the Eastern Standard Time zone in 2017 was at 2:00am on March 12.  So, the first few hours of the day on that date were:

```
   12:00am - 1:00am
    1:00am - 2:00am
   (There was no 2:00am - 3:00am hour due to the "spring ahead")
    3:00am - 4:00am
```

So, if I were to calculate the time differential between 1:00am and 4:00am in that time zone on that date, I'd expect the result to be **2** hours.

However, the code I put together to try to simulate this problem is returning a **3** hour TimeSpan.

Code:

```
TimeZoneInfo easternStandardTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

DateTime oneAm = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 01, 00, 00), easternStandardTime);
DateTime fourAm = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 04, 00, 00), easternStandardTime);

TimeSpan difference = (fourAm - oneAm);

Console.WriteLine(oneAm);
Console.WriteLine(fourAm);
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(oneAm));
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(fourAm));
Console.WriteLine(difference);
```

On my PC, this generates:

```
2017-03-12 01:00:00.000 -5
2017-03-12 04:00:00.000 -4
False
True
03:00:00
```

All of that output is as expected -- except that final value of 3 hours, which as I noted above, I would expect to be 2 hours instead.

Obviously, my code isn't correctly simulating the situation that I have in mind.  What is the flaw?

Comment: What happens if you run this the very next day (not across a time change)?

Comment: @leigero The result TimeSpan is still 3 hours.  The two IsDaylightSavingTime calls both return True.  The timezone offset for both dates shows as -4.

Comment: `DateTime` does not contain any timezone info.  Use `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: @SamAxe I suspect you're probably right, but can you explain further (maybe in an answer on this question)? What's the deal with the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method which takes a time zone and returns a DateTime, if DateTime does not contain any timezone info?

Comment: Bit of a judgment call, but they decided to implement the ~1 nanosecond version.  Instead of the hundreds of nanoseconds it would take to figure out the UTC time.  Speed is a feature too.  DateTimeOffset always stores UTC time internally so doesn't have this problem.  Live and learn, for Microsoft too.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you saying it's the addition/subtraction operators and methods on DateTime that aren't converting to UTC?  If you could expand your comment into an answer, that would help a lot. I'm still unclear on exactly why the DateTime class reports the correct time offsets (-5 and -4 respectively) for my two DateTime objects, yet subtracting them (evidently?) ignores those same offsets.

Comment: DateTime.ToString() is allowed to be slow, strings are for humans, so it does take its merry time to calculate the UTC offset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe:

```c#
// These are just plain unspecified DateTimes
DateTime dtOneAm = new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 01, 00, 00);
DateTime dtFourAm = new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 04, 00, 00);

// The difference is not going to do anything other than 4-1=3
TimeSpan difference1 = dtFourAm - dtOneAm;

// ... but we have a time zone to consider!
TimeZoneInfo eastern = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// Use that time zone to get DateTimeOffset values.
// The GetUtcOffset method has what we need.
DateTimeOffset dtoOneAmEastern = new DateTimeOffset(dtOneAm, eastern.GetUtcOffset(dtOneAm));
DateTimeOffset dtoFourAmEastern = new DateTimeOffset(dtFourAm, eastern.GetUtcOffset(dtFourAm));

// Subtracting these will take the offset into account!
// It essentially does this: [4-(-4)]-[1-(-5)] = 8-6 = 2
TimeSpan difference2 = dtoFourAmEastern - dtoOneAmEastern;

// Let's see the results
Console.WriteLine("dtOneAm: {0:o} (Kind: {1})", dtOneAm, dtOneAm.Kind);
Console.WriteLine("dtFourAm: {0:o} (Kind: {1})", dtFourAm, dtOneAm.Kind);
Console.WriteLine("difference1: {0}", difference1);

Console.WriteLine("dtoOneAmEastern: {0:o})", dtoOneAmEastern);
Console.WriteLine("dtoFourAmEastern: {0:o})", dtoFourAmEastern);
Console.WriteLine("difference2: {0}", difference2);
```

Results:

```
dtOneAm: 2017-03-12T01:00:00.0000000 (Kind: Unspecified)
dtFourAm: 2017-03-12T04:00:00.0000000 (Kind: Unspecified)
difference1: 03:00:00

dtoOneAmEastern: 2017-03-12T01:00:00.0000000-05:00)
dtoFourAmEastern: 2017-03-12T04:00:00.0000000-04:00)
difference2: 02:00:00
```

Note that `DateTime` carries a `DateTimeKind` in its `Kind` property, which is `Unspecified` by default.  It doesn't belong to any particular time zone.  `DateTimeOffset` *doesn't* have a kind, it has an `Offset`, which tells you how far that local time is offset from UTC.  *Neither* of these give you the time zone.  That is what `TimeZoneInfo` object is doing.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

The part I think you are perhaps frustrated with, is that for several historical reasons, the `DateTime` object does not *ever* understand time zones when doing math, even when you might have `DateTimeKind.Local`.  It *could* have been implemented to observe the transitions of the local time zone, but it was not done that way.

You also might be interested in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which gives a very different API for date and time in .NET, in a much more sensible and purposeful way.

```c#
using NodaTime;

...

// Start with just the local values.
// They are local to *somewhere*, who knows where?  We didn't say.
LocalDateTime ldtOneAm = new LocalDateTime(2017, 3, 12, 1, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime ldtFourAm = new LocalDateTime(2017, 3, 12, 4, 0, 0);

// The following won't compile, because LocalDateTime does not reference
// a linear time scale!
// Duration difference = ldtFourAm - ldtOneAm;

// We can get the 3 hour period, but what does that really tell us?
Period period = Period.Between(ldtOneAm, ldtFourAm, PeriodUnits.Hours);

// But now lets introduce a time zone
DateTimeZone eastern = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];

// And apply the zone to our local values.
// We'll choose to be lenient about DST gaps & overlaps.
ZonedDateTime zdtOneAmEastern = ldtOneAm.InZoneLeniently(eastern);
ZonedDateTime zdtFourAmEastern = ldtFourAm.InZoneLeniently(eastern);

// Now we can get the difference as an exact elapsed amount of time
Duration difference = zdtFourAmEastern - zdtOneAmEastern;


// Dump the output
Console.WriteLine("ldtOneAm: {0}", ldtOneAm);
Console.WriteLine("ldtFourAm: {0}", ldtFourAm);
Console.WriteLine("period: {0}", period);

Console.WriteLine("zdtOneAmEastern: {0}", zdtOneAmEastern);
Console.WriteLine("zdtFourAmEastern: {0}", zdtFourAmEastern);
Console.WriteLine("difference: {0}", difference);
```

```
ldtOneAm: 3/12/2017 1:00:00 AM
ldtFourAm: 3/12/2017 4:00:00 AM
period: PT3H

zdtOneAmEastern: 2017-03-12T01:00:00 America/New_York (-05)
zdtFourAmEastern: 2017-03-12T04:00:00 America/New_York (-04)
difference: 0:02:00:00
```

We can see a period of three hours, but it doesn't really mean the same as the elapsed time.  It just means the two local values are three hours apart in their position on a clock.  NodaTime understands the difference between these concepts, while .Net's built-in types do not.

Some follow-up reading for you:

- [What's wrong with DateTime anyway?](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)
- [More Fun with DateTime](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/)
- [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)
- [Five Common Daylight Saving Time Antipatterns of .NET Developers](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/)

Oh, and one other thing.  Your code has this...

```
DateTime oneAm = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 01, 00, 00), easternStandardTime);
```

Since the `DateTime` you create has unspecified kind, you are asking to convert *from your computer's local time zone* to Eastern time.  If you happen to be *not* in Eastern time, your `oneAm` variable might not be 1 AM at all!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I made some minor changes to your code. Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve or not but this will give you what you want...

```
static void Main() {
        TimeZoneInfo easternStandardTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

        DateTime oneAm = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 01, 00, 00), easternStandardTime);
        DateTime fourAm = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 04, 00, 00), easternStandardTime);

        DaylightTime time = timeZone.GetDaylightChanges(fourAm.Year);

        TimeSpan difference = ((fourAm - time.Delta) - oneAm);

        Console.WriteLine(oneAm);
        Console.WriteLine(fourAm);
        Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(oneAm));
        Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(fourAm));
        Console.WriteLine(difference);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why this is necessary, though? I'm still confused by why just subtracting 2017-03-12 01:00 -5 (i.e. 6:00 UTC) from 2017-03-12 04:00 -4 (i.e. 8:00 UTC) yields 3.

Comment: As I understand it, the language can understand that it is in fact when time shifts but when you do the time-span it is not accounted for and is looked at as if you are taking a span between 12/03/2017 01.00.00 and 12/03/2017 04.00.00. Aka 4 -1. I found this article helpful in explaining how Daylight Savings Time is understood. It is towards the bottom : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx

Comment: This is still problematic, as the local time zone is being introduced in the conversion functions.  You're converting *from* local time *to* eastern time.  This is not the same as applying the eastern time zone offset.  Also, the `DaylightTime.Delta` object here is just going to be 1 hour.  It does not do what you think it does.  Really, the `GetDaylightChanges` method is rarely useful.

Answer (score -2):

So this is addressed in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354180(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Basicaly, when subtracting one date from another you should be using `DateTimeOffset.Subtract()` and not arithmetic subtraction as you have here.

```
TimeSpan difference = fourAm.Subtract(oneAm);
```

Yields the expected 2 hour time difference.

Comment: I actually did try using the .Subtract method instead of the minus operator when I was playing around with this prior to posting. However, I was using DateTime objects, not DateTimeOffset, and the code still returned a 3 hour TimeSpan.  I'm starting to suspect that trying to do math with DateTime objects as in my example isn't the right approach, although I don't really understand WHY that is yet.

Comment: Still yields the same 3 hours as up there.

Comment: Can you explain why using DateTime doesn't work? I'm still confused by why subtracting 2017-03-12 01:00 -5 (i.e. 6:00 UTC) from 2017-03-12 04:00 -4 (i.e. 8:00 UTC) yields 3.

Comment: Firstly, `fourAm.Subtract(oneAm)` calls `DateTime.Subtract`, not `DateTimeOffset.Subtract`. Secondly, the documentation you link to says the opposite: it specifically says that in languages that support operator overloading, you can just use `-` instead of calling `Subtract`.