# Calculating for remaining days in current month

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know how to calculate the remaining days of the month e.g (15 Feb 2017 to 28 Feb 2017) without the use of a datetimepicker set at 28 Feb 2017.

Here are my codes for subtraction of 2 datetimepicker:

```
 DateTime startDate =
     (DateTime)dateTimePicker2.Value;

 DateTime endDate =
     (DateTime)dateTimePicker1.Value;

 TimeSpan ts = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

 textBox10.Text = ts.Days.ToString();`
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to go through:

- take your current date
- use [DateTime.AddMonths()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a new date one month from your current date
- create a new date that uses 1 for the day, and the month and year from the future date you just worked out
- subtract your current date from the future date, this will give you a Timespan which contains the number of days difference

You can use the closely related question [*Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1607336/109702) as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, but you can use the `Value` property from your `DateTimePicker` instead. [`DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) is a helpful method.

```
DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2017, 2, 15);
var daysLeft = DateTime.DaysInMonth(beginDate.Year, beginDate.Month) - beginDate.Day;
Console.WriteLine("days from Feb 15 to Feb 28: {0}", daysLeft);
```

Output:

> days from Feb 15 to Feb 28: 13

Comment: Why the downvote please?

Comment: @L.B, the question wasn't off-topic or asking for opinions/advice. The asker obviously wanted to find the last day of a month. I'm using the same object they used in their current code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int days = dt.AddDays(1 - dt.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day - dt.Day;
```