# c# windows form Application for employee management

Tags: c#, winforms

In a C# windows form based application. I used two dateTime pickers,one for From and another for To.

if a employee selecting his leave from may 30 in dateTime picker1 and selecting june 2 in datetime picker2, that makes 4 days of leave.

My question is how can i findout how many days he took leave in may and how many days he took leave in june?

**Update**
I know this, and stuck further

```
DateTime start = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date; 
DateTime end = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date; 
int a = int.Parse(Convert.ToInt32(end.Subtract(start).Days).ToString());
```

Comment: [We can’t rely on other people to do our work for us. Asking others to do our work for us can also be seen as rude. If we try for ourselves, we may succeed.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: We will be interested in knowing what you have do so far and where do are you stuck .. code will be better

Comment: My 4 second search found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Comment: @Lucax he would need this but still he need to find how many days in one month and how many in other !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Comment: actually am a degree student... currently am doing a payroll mangament System..

Comment: Are you get paid for doing payroll management System?

Comment: @NidheeshK dear if you are student, you must try your homework by yourself. that way you will learn better

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As others have pointed out, here it is required to first try to solve the problem yourself and then ask a question when you run into a specific problem. The reason is that most ppl answer the questions in their free time while they are getting paid to develop professionally. They are used to the idea that software development is not done for free, while helping others for their specific problems on SO is.

Comment: a got solution for difference between two days

Comment: @NidheeshK will it work for your requirement ?

Comment: its our finally year project,,,, and we dont anything in this semester,but we have to submit project,so choose C# platform, but while reach to leave part module i got stucked

Comment: DateTime start = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
                DateTime end = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;

                int a = int.Parse(Convert.ToInt32(end.Subtract(start).Days).ToString());

Comment: difffrence between two days its working

Comment: but the thing is,if choose LEAVE FROM:may 30 in datetime picker1 and LEAVE_TO:june 2 in datetimepicker2, how can i findout how many days he took leave in may as well as june..while doing subtract am getting 4.i want ,result in may he took 2 leaves and in june he took 2 leaves

Comment: please help me..ddnt get solution on youtube.. so am stucked

Comment: am not paying.. we have two options in college  either we can ask help of small startup companies or else u should ourself, am doing myself..

Comment: If you have additional information, please edit that into your question.

Comment: Review: `end.Subtract(start).Days` already returns an `int` value. So you don't need to `Convert.ToInt()`. And why would to use `.ToString()` on an int value, only to `int.Parse()` it back into an int?

Comment: This question can be anything else but far away from "too broad"

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code,

here at the end you will get a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) (tabular form) where key will be month number and value is days of in month (here in your question, how many days employee has taken leave)

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 25); //date time picker's date
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2018, 07, 05); //date time picker's date
Dictionary<int, int> daysInMonth = new Dictionary<int, int>();

while(true)
{
    DateTime thisMonthEndDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month));
    if (thisMonthEndDate > endDate)
    {
        thisMonthEndDate = endDate;
        daysInMonth.Add(startDate.Month, (int)(thisMonthEndDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1);
        break;
    }

    daysInMonth.Add(startDate.Month, (int)(thisMonthEndDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1);
    startDate = thisMonthEndDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

and output printing will be

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> keyVal in daysInMonth)
{
    Console.WriteLine("For Month:" + keyVal.Key + " leave count:" + keyVal.Value);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get days per month in a timespan.

```
   for (DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddMonths(1))
   {
       DateTime this_date_start = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
       DateTime this_date_end = this_date_start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
       TimeSpan duration = this_date_end.Subtract(date);
       Console.WriteLine("duration " + date.Month + " = " + duration.Days  + "days");
   }
```

NB: this loop is incomplete: then you have to do this once again outside the loop (this will also catch any shorter than one month spans)

Comment: thank you all for your valuable answers... thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

LINQ make it simple and readable:

```
var from = new DateTime(2018, 5, 28);
var to = new DateTime(2018, 6, 4);

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                       .Select(i => from.Date.AddDays(i))
                       .TakeWhile(date => date <= to.Date)
                       .GroupBy(date => date.Month)
                       .Select(range => (Month: range.Key, Days: range.Count()));

foreach (var month in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Month: {month.Month}, Seek days: {month.Days}");
}

// result:
// Month: 5, Seek days: 4
// Month: 6, Seek days: 4
```

If you need amount of seek days for specific month, make it Dictionary

```
var seekDays = result.ToDictionary(month => month.Month, month => month.SeekDays);

var seekDaysOfMay = seekDays.GetValueOrDefault(5, 0);
```