# C#: How to find difference of days between 2 nullable datetimes?

Tags: c#, datetime

A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days) in regards to calculating the difference in days of 2 datetimes, however both of my datetimes are nullable, which prevents me from using "TotalDays" as is suggested in that question.

```
DateTime? startDate;
DateTime? endDate;

return(d1-d2).TotalDays;  //This won't work
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Make an if statement to see if either value is null, return null if true, take the `.Value` property if false and do the subtraction.

Comment: If either of those are `null`, the result of `d1-d2` will be `null`, so this is also a nullable value, like `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, you need to decide what to do in this case.

Comment: In your sample code, you never initialize (or use) `startDate` or `endDate`, and neither `d1` nor `d2` are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue)
{
    return (startDate.Value - endDate.Value).TotalDays;
}
else
{
    // handle one or more dates being null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value it's null that will throw an exeption,

to prevent this just add a "?" like this:

```
return(d1-d2)?.TotalDays;
```

So if the object is null it won't go any further

Comment: Actually, the original code won't even compile, but this is correct. If the OP does not want `null` in return though, he will need to decide what to return instead, something simple as `return (d1-d2)?.TotalDays ?? 0;` might be enough.