# Subtract DateOnly in C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dateonly

In C# I can't use subtraction with `DateOnly` variables, unlike `DateTime`. Is there any explanation?

```
  var a = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
  var b = new DateTime(1999, 01, 01);

  //var c = a.Subtract(b);
  var c = a - b;

  var d = new DateOnly(2000, 01, 01);
  var e = new DateOnly(1999, 01, 01);

  var f = d - e; // Error - Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateOnly' and 'DateOnly'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Comment: You can use extension .ToDateTime(bool timeOnly) on your DateOnly so you can have behaviour of DateTime

Comment: @Amit Verma Thanks for answer, but not really. I need to use DateOnly structure instead of DateTime, which is used in link.

Comment: Since you aren't asking for a solution i figure my answer will be sufficient?

Comment: When it was [introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/): "a DateOnly represents the entire date (from the start of the day through the end of the day)". Subtracting one of those from another would be problematic because there are 3 possible answers depending on what inclusivity you would want to consider for the start and end points.

Comment: @rbdeebk thanks for answer! I'm more interested in the reason

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Conceptually `DateOnly` represents an entire day, not midnight or any other specific time on a given day, such that subtracting one `DateOnly` from another cannot logically return a `TimeSpan` as with `DateTime`'s [subtraction operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-op-subtraction(system-datetime-system-datetime)).

If you want to perform arithmetic on `DateOnly`s, you need to be explicit about the desired unit.

`DateOnly` has a [`DayNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.daynumber?view=net-6.0) property, that returns the number of *whole days* since 01/01/0001, so if you want to determine the number of whole days between 2 `DateOnly` values, you can do the following:

```
var d = new DateOnly(2000, 01, 01);
var e = new DateOnly(1999, 01, 01);

var daysDifference = d.DayNumber - e.DayNumber;
```

Comment: Hi, If we suppose, one of them is nullable how can I do that?

Comment: @L.Kvri Use `.Value` or cast to `DateOnly`, along with any necessary null checks, as with other nullable value types.

Comment: Your explanation should be the error message returned by .net!

Answer (score 9):

You can use DayNumber property to do the subtraction, f will hold the number of days between d and e.

```
var f = d.DayNumber - e.DayNumber;
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:  June 2, 2022 - June 1, 2022 = ? Is the answer 1 or is the answer 2?  It encompasses 2 full days, but the difference is 1.  By forcing us to use DayNumber, there is only one possible answer.

Comment: The answer is 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an exact reason as to why they haven't made it possible. But if you look at the documententation [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) it doesn't contain the operator addition and subtraction. [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) does.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question why - [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) in operators section it just doesn't have subtraction implemented while [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-op-subtraction(system-datetime-system-datetime)) does have one. What you can do is create your own extension similar to this one.